# Is there an API for online purchases using a credit card for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, credit-card

I am developing an application for both: iOS and the Android platform which sells actual items.

Is there any API that users can use to pay with a credit card for online purchases that I can use with my application?

I'm looking for some API similar to paypal: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries but I need a credit card version.

Comment: I found all of the content in my answer by just doing a quick google search. Please look a little harder next time.

Answer (score 1):

ZooZ has an excellent API for in-app purchases.
The solution supports both credit cards and PayPal.
Check them out at [www.zooz.co](http://www.zooz.co)

Answer (score 0):

This is the android [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) for In-App purchasing. [This is a tutorial](http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/) for iPhone in app billing.

Comment: but i am selling physical goods. according to the guideline, i cant use in app billing API. i want to have some API like paypal

Comment: I didn't notice that the android API didn't allow the selling of physical goods until just now. So you won't be able to use that I guess. Just a word of caution about the Paypal android API, last time I tried to use it, it was horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires that all in-app purchases on iOS be processed via their App Store.

[Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/) has an API that can be used for processing payments on both Android and iOS (via the App Store).

Comment: Apple:
11.3 APPS USING IAP TO PURCHASE PHYSICAL GOODS OR GOODS AND SERVICES USED OUTSIDE OF THE APPLICATION WILL BE REJECTED

Android: 
You can use in-app billing to sell only digital content. You cannot use in-app billing to sell physical goods, personal services, or anything that requires physical delivery.